# Backend form validation callback approach | vuex store | vuejs

Tags: validation, model, store, vuex

My question is about handling "database validation errors" to the user using a Vuex store. (see image below) 
Any advice on how to handle this ?
[image]

Then display my errors specified and "positioned" by field.
Something like this:

```
<label>Title</label>
<input type="text">
<p v-if="errors.title">{{errors.title}}</p>
```

My first thought was to pass the 'db errors' received by the 'vuex store action' too a 'store state attribute', and use a computed property with a "store getter" in the vuejs component to display the error, but this just doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: That's a good question. What are the drawbacks you see from storing the errors in the store? Just feels 'dirty'?

Comment: What if it's in a Vuex module dedicated to manage errors? It could act as an Error Bag, where the component that displays error messages would go to see if there's an error for a field.

Comment: mmm, that is kind if my intention but i am afraid to over-complicate stuff, but yeah i could make a "error property" and a "succes property" in the vuex store, and fill these properties based on the "DB model response", then can use one 'computed property' in my vuejs component with some logic to display an error or succes message (again i hope im not over-complicating here :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this json model for getting data from the server: `{status: 0, result: {}, error: {}}`.
In that case you can check the `status` attribute, for the success of the rest api call. So depends on the `status`, you can handle either the `error`, or the `result` variable.

On the server side, if any error / exception caught, you can send back to the client (specifically), in the error variable.

In your case, e.g.: you caught a db error on a server side, you define status for that (e.g.) *430*, you send back the message with the error and the status code, that way you can handle nicely the problem.

I hope it helps! :)

Comment: Great, will follow this up, Thnks alot!

Comment: you are welcome! If its working accpet the answer, or give some feedback about the problem. ;)

Comment: I will :), would like to ask one more question though, what do you think about this approach in general? , i also read something about using SESSIONS for handeling errors from the backend, (because its more flexible guess?) , would like to know some opinions

Comment: Actually everything depends on the goal. My last job was a simple webpage. The average user doesn't care about the spec error. I always notify the user "error 432: Database Error" or "error 480: Loading error, please refresh the page"..
But, I made a spec log to the console, so during the support, I can ask the user to check the console for the spec error, But the error code is for that too.
On the other hand if there is an error on the server side, you should write that to the log.

Comment: I think its clearer then storing this information in the session. Session is use for the current user data. But never forget You must not store sensitive data on the client side. The rest api token provide you Authentication and Authorization as well. So with api token you can determine the user, and the user rights. :)
e.g. the admin can see the spec error but average user can not.. etc

Comment: Excuse me, i was not very clear in my explanation, it's about the form validation, for example: column `title` must be unique. i updated my question with how i want to display my errors

Comment: I see, Yes this is one of the solution what you wrote. If you use some gui vue lib, there is other pretty solutions. I used e.g. bootstrap-vue, what has [fromgroup](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-group) and it handles this error notifications well.